# How Rails understands what request is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I wrote this code:

```
module UniversityFinder
  def define_shortcut_part
    r=request
    subs=request.subdomains
    if subs.length>1
      subs[1]
    else
      subs[0]
    end
  end
  def university
  university=University.find_by_shortcut(define_shortcut_part)
  end
end
```

Which suits my one needs, in separate file, and included module in one of my controllers.

The thing is, that I expected `uninitialized constant` error from Rails for this `request` variable.

On the opposite, it works fine and does what I wanted.

This is purely curiosity question regarding Rails source code ('rails magic') for better understanding. This variable nor even called like instance variable (`@request`), but still Rails gets this local. Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails I believe, it is just how ruby modules work, when you include them in a class their instance methods become like other instance methods for that class (so it's as if you defined your method inside the controller and simply called the `request` method on your controller object).

Comment: I see, that makes sense